# Comparsion method violates its general contract error while installing NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, java-8, illegalargumentexception, failed-installation

I've had the same screen error that keeps me from installing NetBeans, it appears right after the terms agreement, I have uninstalled and reinstalled JDK and older Java version multiple times but it keeps failing. Any suggestión on what to do?

[image: Error screen]

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what to do: _"get more details about the issue in the installer log file..."_. So update your question with the information logged to the installer log file. Also, update your question to specify the versions of Java and NetBeans that are being used because you may be trying to use NetBeans with an unsupported version of Java. In particular, note that release 12.6 and later of NetBeans do not support Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in the JDK. How to solve it is described [here](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/discussions/6361).

Comment: It's simply wrong to claim that this is _"a bug in the JDK"_ based on the limited information provided in the question. We don't even know which JDK method is violating its contract! The JDK support team were unable to reproduce the problem on Windows 10 or Windows 11, testing with six different releases of Java. They are still [awaiting further information from the person who created the bug](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8305072), and that bug has _"Resolution:Incomplete"_. No conclusions can be made until the OP shows us what is in their installer log file.